# Mysql не возвращает результат запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Совсем ничего не понимаю, запрос, вроде, правильный. Но не выводит строку с нужным id;

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "bd");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" .     $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    $id = $_POST['productID'];

    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT SS_products FROM title WHERE id = $id");
    echo $res;

?>
```

Запрос то вроде правильный, но результат запроса пустой

Comment: $res - это не результат возвращаемый запросом, а дескриптор для доступа к данным. прочитайте документацию на mysqli->query и посмотрите там примеры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобных вопросов уже много было. Да и в документации всё подробно прописано:
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

> В случае успешного выполнения запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN mysqli_query() вернет объект mysqli_result.

Смотрим, что с этим делать и видим:

> mysqli_result::fetch_all — Выбирает все строки из результирующего набора и помещает их в ассоциативный массив, обычный массив или в оба

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT SS_products FROM title WHERE id = $id");
$result = $res->fetch_all();
print_r($result);
```